# Profile views do not display usernames/details

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am making a function to display the profile details of a user on my Rails app. However, when I try to view the profile of a user, it displays this error.

```
undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass
```

Here's the controller snippet for the show action:

```
def show
  @profile = Profile.find_by(user_id: :user_id)
end
```

View:

```
<p>
  <strong>Username:</strong>
  <%= @profile.username %>
</p>
```

I know I should be using [:id], but I switched to using :user_id after an issue happened where the profile would not be found due to Rails passing the current user's ID as the profile ID, which threw things off.

Comment: try @profile = Profile.find_by(user_id: params[:id])

Comment: `@profile` is nil because you are searching the `profiles` table for a record having `user_id` equal to the symbol `:user_id`. Check your server logs and show in your question what the parameters look like when the `#show` action is called. It's possible you should be using `Profile.find_by(user_id: params[:user_id])`, but hard to say without knowing what your params look like.

Comment: the thing is, it seems to find the record, but will not display the data

Comment: @widjajayd i think that worked. i'm new to rails (this is a project)- do you mind helping me understand why this worked while my original solution didn't?

Comment: @vjhbr not OP but in ruby there are strings like in most languages, but there are also symbols (denoted like `:symbol_name`). Symbols are similar to strings (see this for the differences https://reactive.io/tips/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings), but in this case the difference is that your telling rails to find a profile with a user id of symbol `:user_id`. Then rails goes to your db and looks for a profile with a user_id of `:user_id`. It doens't find any because your ids are probably ints.

Comment: The way how @widjajayd's solution works is that it calls the param method (remember that you can exclude parenthesis in ruby methods) which is essentially a hash with some extra stuff, so you can access it like a normal ruby hash using `[]` notation. Rails does some magic to populate the hash with things you might want like headers, path params, query params, and some other stuff. `params[:user_id]` is essentially, i passed in this thing called `user_id`, and I want to get the value of it in my code.